# Sorting DIV with IDs in ascending and descending order

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, sorting

I'm having trouble trying to sort a list of buttons with content in ascending and descending order in HTML/CSS/JAVASCRIPT (ie. Anteater, Baboon, Cat...).

Originally, I wanted to use my BUTTON IDs to sort but I couldn't work it out.

I've looked on the net and found some code that works using text inside a DIV/button, but the code doesn't work on my page properly.

Here's the sample code that works:

```js
var $divs = $("button.bingo_button_4");

$('#alphBnt').on('click', function() {
  var alphabeticallyOrderedDivs = $divs.sort(function(a, b) {
    return $(a).find("h1").text() > $(b).find("h1").text();
  });
  $("#bingo_width_x").html(alphabeticallyOrderedDivs);
});

$('#numBnt').on('click', function() {
  var numericallyOrderedDivs = $divs.sort(function(a, b) {
    return $(a).find("h1").text() < $(b).find("h1").text();
  });
  $("#bingo_width_x").html(numericallyOrderedDivs);
});
```

```css
body {
  background: #eee;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="alphBnt">Ascending</button>
  <button id="numBnt">Descending</button>
    <div id="bingo_width_x">
  <button class="bingo_button_4">
  <h1>B</h1><DIV>asdf</DIV>
  </button>
    
  <button class="bingo_button_4">
    <h1>A</h1><DIV>asdf</DIV>
  </button>
    
  <button class="bingo_button_4">
    <h1>D</h1><DIV>asdf</DIV>
  </button>
    
  <button class="bingo_button_4">
    <h1>C</h1><DIV>asdf</DIV>
  </button>

  <button class="bingo_button_4">
    <h1>E</h1><DIV>asdf</DIV>
  </button>
  
    <button class="bingo_button_4">
    <h1>F</h1><DIV>asdf</DIV>
  </button>
  
    <button class="bingo_button_4">
    <h1>G</h1><DIV>asdf</DIV>
  </button>
  
    <button class="bingo_button_4">
    <h1>H</h1><DIV>asdf</DIV>
  </button>
  
    <button class="bingo_button_4">
    <h1>U</h1><DIV>asdf</DIV>
  </button>

</div>
```

Here's my code:

```js
function order_bingo_item(text_order)
{

  var order_type = text_order;
  var $divs = $("button.bingo_button_4");

if (order_type=='ascending')
 {
  var alphabeticallyOrderedDivs = $divs.sort(function (a, b) {
        return $(a).find("idn").text() > $(b).find("idn").text();
    });
    $("#bingo_width").html(alphabeticallyOrderedDivs);
 }
else
if (order_type=='descending')
 {
  var alphabeticallyOrderedDivs = $divs.sort(function (a, b) {
        return $(a).find("idn").text() < $(b).find("idn").text();
    });
    $("#bingo_width").html(alphabeticallyOrderedDivs);
 }
  

}
```

```css
.bingo_button_4 idn
{
  color: black;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="alphBnt" onclick=order_bingo_item('ascending');>Ascending</button>
<button id="numBnt" onclick=order_bingo_item('descending');>Descending</button>


<div id="bingo_width" class="bingo_width" style="border:solid 2px; width:px;">
  
  <button id="ID_grid_101_3_user" class="bingo_button_4">
    <idn>3</idn>    
    <div style="position:relative; width:100%; height:100%; text-align:center;"> 
    bear
    </div>
</button>

<button id="ID_grid_101_0_user" class="bingo_button_4">
    <idn>0</idn>    
    <div style="position:relative; width:100%; height:100%; text-align:center;"> 
    ant-eater
    </div>
</button>

<button id="ID_grid_101_15_user" class="bingo_button_4">
    <idn>15</idn>    
    <div style="position:relative; width:100%; height:100%; text-align:center;"> 
    cobra
    </div>
</button>


</div>
```

Basically, it's not sorting each button using "idn" in each button properly.  My list of buttons is a lot bigger than this and the order is all wrong (like a random order).  What seems to be the problem?

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```js
function order_bingo_item(text_order)
{

  var order_type = text_order;
  var $divs = $("button.bingo_button_4");

if (order_type=='ascending')
 {
  var alphabeticallyOrderedDivs = $divs.sort(function (a, b) {
        return $(a).find("idn").text() - $(b).find("idn").text();
    });
    $("#bingo_width").html(alphabeticallyOrderedDivs);
 }
else
if (order_type=='descending')
 {
  var alphabeticallyOrderedDivs = $divs.sort(function (a, b) {
        return $(b).find("idn").text() - $(a).find("idn").text();
    });
    $("#bingo_width").html(alphabeticallyOrderedDivs);
 }
  

}
```

```css
.bingo_button_4 idn
{
  color: black;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="alphBnt" onclick=order_bingo_item('ascending');>Ascending</button>
<button id="numBnt" onclick=order_bingo_item('descending');>Descending</button>


<div id="bingo_width" class="bingo_width" style="border:solid 2px; width:px;">
  
  <button id="ID_grid_101_3_user" class="bingo_button_4">
    <idn>3</idn>    
    <div style="position:relative; width:100%; height:100%; text-align:center;"> 
    bear
    </div>
</button>

<button id="ID_grid_101_0_user" class="bingo_button_4">
    <idn>0</idn>    
    <div style="position:relative; width:100%; height:100%; text-align:center;"> 
    ant-eater
    </div>
</button>

<button id="ID_grid_101_15_user" class="bingo_button_4">
    <idn>15</idn>    
    <div style="position:relative; width:100%; height:100%; text-align:center;"> 
    cobra
    </div>
</button>


</div>
```

Sorting integers is bit different. You need to do

`a - b` instead of `a > b`

Comment: great answer only apply a-b or wise-versa instead of a > b

Comment: That worked for me.  How did you come across this solution?  Is there a way to sort through ID instead of having to create the "idn" field that I have in the code above?

Comment: All details are given in [`Array.prototype.sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)